# How do I set default font for Amharic on Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, default

I have this font that I want to use for Amharic/Ethiopic, while leaving the default for other characters, notably Latin. The problem is my Ubuntu OS seem to have a random way of choosing from among the numerous Ethiopic fonts I have installed. I don't wan't to choose my preferred Ethiopic font as the system default either as I don't like the Latin characters it has. Any advice on how I can manipulate or configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link on how to enable Amharic Input on Ubuntu 12.04

http://amebels.blogspot.com/2014/03/enabling-amharic-input-on-ubuntu-1204.html

EDIT: the steps outlined are merely copied from the link above.

**Installation Steps**

```
wget -qO - http://packages.sil.org/sil.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.sil.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-kmfl  kmfl-keyboard-sil-ethiopic fonts-sil-abyssinicasil
```

After installation follow the following configuration steps

1. Choose IBus as the input method

   - Open 'Language Support '
   - Choose 'ibus' from drop down following 'Keyboard input method system: ' option
   - Close
2. Setting up Amharic

   - Open 'Keyboard Input Methods '
   - Go to 'Input Method' tab
   - Enable 'Customize active input method'
   - Select your 'Other' -> 'SIL Ethopic #.#' (#.# may change from time to time as upgrades are made) from the drop down menu and click 'Add button'
   - Move it up to the top so that whenever you run ibus you will be directly able to type in your language.
   - Close
   - Logout and Login
3. Running IBus on System Startup

   - Open 'Startup Applications'
   - Click on the "Add" button
   - Write command as: "ibus-daemon" and give whatever name you want
   - Click on the "Add" button
   - Enable it
   - Close

You should get a keyboard icon on the top panel near the digital clock. You can use to choose 'Other - SIL Ethiopic #.#' or press 'Ctrl + Space' keys to start typing in አማርኛ።

The guide was made by following the instruction in the following links;
http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_KMFL_on_Ubuntu
http://packages.sil.org/
http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=AbyssinicaSIL_Download
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this blog post might contain a solution to the problem, it would be preferable to include the necessary steps in your answer.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to answer, but what I was looking for was a means to control what font my system chooses for Amharic. Currently I have no control on how it chooses the fonts. I am already able to type in Amharic; I even written a blog with instructions on how to enable it. BTW, this also concerns other languages with non-Latin script.